# Error message from using lapply in nested loops for list() of randomized networks

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops, igraph

I'm making lists of random networks and generating a dateframe of their info. I'm doing this in nested loops of code. My code does not finish, and when I've stopped the run in my .RMD chunk (after RStudio crashes) I get the following error message:

```
no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
1.
lapply(random_nws, cluster_optimal)
```

This is a sample of the code in the same format.

```
random_nw_metrics <- data.frame( #to fill in
 
# Community 
  "count_communities" = NA,
  "ave_membership" = NA,
  "sd_membership" = NA,
  "modularity" = NA,

# General Network 
  # "assortativity" = NA, 
  "ave_distance" = NA,
  "degree_ave" = NA,
  "degree_sd" = NA,
  "density" = NA,
  "diameter" = NA,
  "reciprocity" = NA,
  "transitivity" = NA
) 


for (i in 1:180){ # it was "i in 1:nrow(df)", but that's not useful to you
  
set.seed(1)
random_nws <- list()
for (j in seq_len(1000L)) {
  
    Start = sample(15, 200, replace=TRUE)  # "15" and "20" change based on values from the df
    End   = sample(15, 200, replace=TRUE)
    df = data.frame(Start, End)
    
    ass.label <- data.frame("node" = 1:15, "type" = 0) # for assortativity labels
    ass.label$type <- +(match(ass.label$node, sample(x = 15, size = 5) ) > 0)
    ass.label[c("node", "type")][is.na(ass.label[c("node", "type")])] <- 0
    
    random_nws[[j]]<- graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = ass.label, directed=TRUE)
}


random_cs <- lapply(random_nws, cluster_optimal)
nw <- random_nws[[i]]

random_nw_metrics <- rbind(random_nw_metrics, data.frame(
    
# Community 
  "count_communities" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) mean(length(x)))),
  "ave_membership" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) mean(membership(x)))),
  "sd_membership" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) sd(membership(x)))),
  "modularity" = mean(sapply(random_cs, function(x) mean(modularity(x)))),

# General Network 
  # "assortativity" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(assortativity(x, V(x)$Type, directed = T)))), # this isn't working ignore it for now
  "ave_distance" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(mean_distance(x)))),
  "degree_ave" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(degree(x)))),
  "degree_sd" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) sd(degree(x)))),
  "density" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(edge_density(x)))),
  "diameter" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(diameter(x)))),
  "reciprocity" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(reciprocity(x)))),
  "transitivity" = mean(sapply(random_nws, function(x) mean(transitivity(x))))
)) 

}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this, I'm not sure what to do about it since I need the communities for some of my measures.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problem with your code. You can try the code below, which may be more efficient to get the desired output

```
nw_metrics <- replicate(180, {
  random_nws <- replicate(
    1000L,
    {
      Start <- sample(15, 200, replace = TRUE)
      End <- sample(15, 200, replace = TRUE)
      df <- data.frame(Start, End)
      ass.label <- data.frame("node" = 1:15, "type" = 0) # for assortativity labels
      ass.label$type <- +(match(ass.label$node, sample(x = 15, size = 5)) > 0)
      ass.label[c("node", "type")][is.na(ass.label[c("node", "type")])] <- 0
      list(graph_from_data_frame(df, vertices = ass.label, directed = TRUE))
    }
  )
  random_cs <- lapply(random_nws, cluster_optimal)
  community <- rowMeans(
    sapply(
      random_cs,
      function(x) {
        mbx <- membership(x)
        c(
          count_communities = mean(length(x)),
          ave_membership = mean(mbx),
          sd_membership = sd(mbx),
          modularity = mean(modularity(x))
        )
      }
    )
  )
  generalnetwork <- rowMeans(
    sapply(
      random_nws,
      function(x) {
        degx <- degree(x)
        c(
          ave_distance = mean(mean_distance(x)),
          degree_ave = mean(degx),
          degree_sd = sd(degx),
          density = mean(edge_density(x)),
          diameter = mean(diameter(x)),
          reciprocity = mean(reciprocity(x)),
          transitivity = mean(transitivity(x))
        )
      }
    )
  )
  list(c(community, generalnetwork))
})
random_nw_metrics <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, nw_metrics))
```

and the output looks like

```
  count_communities ave_membership sd_membership modularity ave_distance
1               3.3       2.220000     0.9148421  0.2031175     1.421429
2               3.6       2.220000     1.0218422  0.1942025     1.403333
3               3.6       2.360000     0.9869272  0.2092750     1.415714
4               3.3       2.060000     0.9003820  0.1961875     1.400000
5               3.7       2.233333     1.0169882  0.1933500     1.413810
  degree_ave degree_sd  density diameter reciprocity transitivity
1   26.66667  4.702093 0.952381      2.4   0.4487476    0.8116972
2   26.66667  4.827348 0.952381      2.2   0.4631853    0.8439533
3   26.66667  5.058985 0.952381      2.0   0.4384173    0.8207699
4   26.66667  4.833340 0.952381      2.2   0.4490952    0.8464840
5   26.66667  4.816635 0.952381      2.2   0.4396883    0.8309121
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! do you think there's a reason I keep getting that error message then? or might that be a problem on my end in terms of computer specs, package/R version, or impatience for the code to run?

Comment: @user13822027 I guess you can clean up all auxiliary files (keep your source code) and run it again. Maybe some temporary files are damaged but saved, which affects your script running.